# ::selection span is not as high as actual <span/> tag container, only as high as text

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, selection

In Electron (a Chrome window) I am text-selecting a number of multi-line `<div/>` tags which have a number of `<span/>` tags. However the ::selection spans don't meet between the lines, i.e. the span is not as high as the actual tag. See image here:

[image: Screenshot of span selection]

I can verify the `<span/>` tags are 19px, as high as the `<div/>` tags, and there is no padding or margin assigned to the divs or spans at all.

I think it is something related to display inline-block of spans but I tried different displays and it did not solve it.

**div container style:**

```
.line {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

**span style:**

```
.word {
    color: black;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

I have a css pseudo element to color the **selection span**:

```
::selection {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.99);
}
```

I want the selection spans to fill the whole span tag and meet, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

[In this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3L678p5/2/) the selection spans do fill the div... I'm starting to think this could be dependent on the browser?

**EDIT 2**

Yes in fact the same fiddle in the latest Chrome fills the spans but in the latest Firefox it doesn't.

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Might want to play with the `line-height` property.

Comment: Unfortunately changing `line-height` does not change the selection span wrapping only the text, so there is still a gap.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with an example?

Comment: @Charlie see my edits looks like might be browser dependent?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is. You could create your own selection handling with some JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event